# Inheritance in C++; Is class data inherited as well?

Tags: c++, inheritance

So if there is a function `greet` in parent class `Base` and it is virtual.

There's a property named `name` in parent class.

Now a class named `Child` inherits it and `greet` is not implemented but the property `name` has changed in the `Child` class. So when calling `Child.greet()` does it uses the Child's `name` or the Parent's `name`?

Explanation on the reason of the design decision is much appreciated.

Comment: You can't "change" the name of a member in a derived class in C++.

Comment: I think you mean the property `value` has changed? The property name can't be changed.

Comment: Clarification: `name` is a member variable. It contains a `value`. What do you mean by property?

Answer (score 1):

It uses the value of `name` at the point of the calling. If the child sets the name before the call to `greet` then it uses the value set by the child. If the child sets the name after the call to `greet` then it uses the default value or whatever has been set before the call.

Answer (score 1):

[I edited the question to clarify the formatting.]

There are two possible situations here.

1. If the `name` property is private and redefined in `Child` then there are two separate variables, each with its own value. The `greet` method sees only its own. Was this the intent?
2. If the `name` property is not redefined there is only one property and one value. The `greet` method returns that value.

Either way it's the same answer: the `greet` method returns the value in `Base`. Properties are not virtualised. Only methods can be virtualised.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try it out to see? This prints "hello Base". Because you're calling Base's greet() method (there is no other), it will access Base's name member variable (generally in C++ member variables are not referred to as a 'property'.). Hope I understood your question.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Base
{
    string name;

public:
    Base() : name(" Base") { }

    virtual string greet()
    {
        return string("hello") + name;
    }
};

class Child : public Base
{
    // bad practice, hiding Base's name member by doing this
    string name;

public:
    Child() : name(" Child") { }
};

int main() {

    Child* child = new Child;
    // prints "hello Base"
    cout << child->greet();
    delete child;

    // same result if calling through a Base pointer (or reference)
    Base* base = new Base;
    // prints "hello Base"
    cout << base->greet();
    delete base;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is dangerous and should be avoided, you have hidden `Base::name` with `Child::name` which creates a lot of confusion.